# Linking to a specific tab

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I am web designer /css / html coder with no much experience in jQuery. I will appreciate some help on the following script. Basically I have a 3 tab form page. I want to be able to link to the form page from 3 different urls, linking to their respective tab open and selected.

The existing jQuery is

```
    function tabcomponent() {
    $('.tabset li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var index = $('.tabset li a').index(this) + 1;
        var selector = 'div#' + index;
        $('.tab-wrapper > div').hide();
        $('.tab-wrapper ' + selector).show();
        $('.tabset li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
};
```

The html is

```
<div class="component tab">
<nav id="nav">
  <ul class="tabset">
    <li><a class="active" href="#"><span>Option  1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Option 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Option 3</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="tab-wrapper">
<div id="1">
<form class="search" action="#">
<fieldset>
  <header>
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="row-holder">
    <input id="checkbox7" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox7">Lorem ipsum</label>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<div id="2">
<form class="search" action="#">
  <div class="form-wrapper">
  <fieldset>
    <header>
      <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="row-holder">
      <input id="checkbox7" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
      <label for="checkbox7">Lorem ipsum</label>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  </div>
  <input type="reset" class="search" value="Clear">
  <input type="submit" class="search" value="Search">
</form>
</div>
<div id="3">
<fieldset>
  <header>
    <h2>Heading 3</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="row-holder">
    <input id="checkbox7" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox7">Lorem ipsum</label>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone explain to me what needs to be added in my Jquery /  html.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the links you're creating to the page you need to include a resource identifier or a query string to identity which tab needs to be open:

http://www.page.com/index.html#link1 (resource identifier)
http://www.page.com/index.html?tab=link1 (query string)

and then in the page with the tabs you need to use some javascript to check for the existence of the parameter. You can access this by using location.href in javascript and the indexOf to find out if the param exists. Based on this you can set one of the tabs to be 'active'

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I understand I need to use query string in my links. How I go about using the javascript you suggested there on the actual page to test the parameter?